# SQL Multiple Joins Query

Tags: sql

Here I have two tables committee_colleges and colleges.
Structure of tables is something like this

committee_colleges

```
    committeeCollegeId collegeId committeeMemberId
    1                  2         1
    2                  2         2 
    3                  3         2
```

I am storing committeeMemberId from committeeMember table.And one college can have multiple committee Members.How can I wite a query to display only the colleges assigned to specific committee Member.
For Example,if committeeMember by id=2 has logged in I want to display colleges by id=2,3.

In college table I have like this,

```
    collegeId typeName
    1         AICTE
    2         NCTE
    3         NTCS
```

This is Committee Member table

```
    committeeMemberId name
    1                 xyz
    2                 abc
```

Now I am writing something like this,but i know its wrong because I dont know how to take it from College table since I am displaying College details.

```
SELECT cc.committeeCollegeId as committeeCollegeId,
       c.collegeId as collegeId,
       cc.committeeMemberId as committeeMemberId
FROM committee_college as cc
left outer join College as c
    on cc.collegeId = c.collegeId
where cc.committeeMemberId=:committeeMemberId
order by cc.committeeCollegeId asc
```

Can anyone tell how to display colleges based on its assignment to particular committeeMember?

Comment: Expected result please

Comment: When i login using memberId=2 I need to display collegeId=2,3 colleges.Based on CommitteeMemberId I need to display respective assigned colleges

Comment: What Columns value you want in the Output as you are mentioning about colleges but apart from collegeid you are not selecting anything from College table and that you could get from the committee_college table too. If you specify the expected output with the columns name it would be helpful for someone who would answer your question.

Comment: @SachinHR https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ - show us the expected result(formated), Don't forget to put it in your question, not in comment

Comment: In collegetable I have typeName column.I want to display output of typeName.Only one column i need to display in output that is typeName

Comment: If same committee member is assigned same college twice i am getting same college twice in table.How can i make it to display only once even if he is assigned same college twice?

Comment: you need to use `DISTINCT`, but i guess in that case you have some app/data problems, so you should seek not having a committee assigned twice or more to same college

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you need `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT C.typeName --<<== put here all the columns that you want in output
FROM    committee_colleges CC
        INNER JOIN college C
            ON C.collegeId = CC.collegeId
WHERE   CC.committeeMemberId = 2 --<<== your input parameter
```

**EDIT:** added `DISTINCT`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want typeName column in output.But I dont have it in committee_colleges table.It is there in college table

Comment: C.* means it returns all columns from C aliased table, which is college. So typeName is being returned by query. Which other columns do you need in output? i will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yea.Only typeName i needed.Thank you.Its working fine.

Comment: If same committee member is assigned same college twice i am getting same college twice in table.How can i make it to display only once even if he is assigned same college twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sql statement for the same

```
DECLARE @committeeMemberId INT = 2  -- Id of Committee member

;WITH CTE_MemberCommittee AS
(
    SELECT  CollegeId 
    FROM    committee_colleges
    WHERE   committeeMemberId = @committeeMemberId
)

SELECT  collegeId, typeName
FROM    college
WHERE   collegeId IN (SELECT CollegeId FROM CTE_MemberCommittee)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @LoginCommitteeMemberId INT=2
SELECT t2.Name AS MemberName,
       t3.TypeName AS CollageName
  FROM committee_college t1
   INNER JOIN Committee_Member t2 
    ON t1.committeeMemberId = t2.committeeMemberId 
  INNER JOIN College as t3 
    ON t1.collegeId = t3.collegeId 

  WHERE t1.committeeMemberId = @LoginCommitteeMemberId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple **inner join** for that,

If you want collegename based on memberId use following query,

```
select a.collegeid,a.typeName from
college a, committee_colleges b, committe_member c
where a.collegeid = b.collegeid and
b.committeememberid = c.committeeMemberId
and c.committeeMemberId = '2'
```

If you want collegename based on committemember name then use following query,

```
select a.collegeid,a.typeName from
college a, committee_colleges b, committe_member c
where a.collegeid = b.collegeid and
b.committeememberid = c.committeeMemberId
and c.Name = 'xyz'
```

Hope it will help.